# Existence of Limits in Category theory in Roman's book

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I am self-reading *An Introduction To The Language Of Category* by Roman and having some questions about the set-up for proving the existence of limits.

In the book, the hom-classes are assumed to be sets. A screenshot of the book (parts of page 109 & 110) regarding my questions is attached at the end of the post.

My first question is "the product of a small diagram" (The 2nd sentence in the first paragraph). The product is defined for a diagram with no morphisms (except for identities). Then how to define the product of a small diagram? Do we ignore all morphisms other than identities?

The second question is the finiteness of in-degree $m_k$ (In the final paragraph). We only assume $\mathbb{D}$ to be a small diagram, so for $X\in $ Ob$(\mathbb{D})$, Hom(X,X) can be a countably infinite set. Then the in-degree may be infinite.

Finally, if $X\in $ Ob$(\mathbb{D})$ has no arrow entering $X$, then the in-degree should be counted as 1, right? (i.e. we consider identity when counting in-degree) Then $D_2$ in Figure 61 should have 3 copies instead of 2?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How is a diagram defined in this context?

Comment: For the first question, I think you have some confusion about where the limit actually lives (if I understand your question correctly). Remember, the category $\mathbb{D}$ is just an index category (i.e. a category used for indexing purposes). The limit (or product in this case) is an object that lives in the target category of your diagram. So the product of a small diagram really means "the product of the image of the small diagram"

Comment: @Berci A diagram in a category C is defined to be a functor from an index category J.

Comment: @Ray In the book, a (binary) product is defined as follows. Let $\mathbb{D}$ be a diagram consisting of two objects A and B with no morphisms. Any limit of $\mathbb{D}$ is called a product of A and B. Thus, I am wondering by the product of a small diagram, how to deal with the morphisms (because a product is defined for a diagram with no morphisms)?